How can I test the @Retry and @Fallback annotations in OpenLiberty?
I have the next methods in my service class that try to send an email. If my email client throws a RuntimeException, it will make 4 retries to call the email client, and send the email. In case of an error after the 4th retry it will revert to the sendEmailFallback method.
@Retry(maxRetries = 4, delay = 1000, jitter = 200, retryOn = RuntimeException.class)
@Fallback(fallbackMethod = "sendEmailFallback")
public String sendEmailNow(EmailData data) {
    client.sendEmail(data);
    return "Email sent successfully!";
}

public String sendEmailFallback(EmailData data) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed to send email after retries. Executing fallback method.");
    return "Failed to send email after retries. Executing fallback method.";
}

How can I test this?
Currently, my application uses test containers for end to end testing. I am loading all the necessary configuration files to my open liberty container to execute the tests that assert a 200 status code. Once the test containers are up, I cannot modify any configuration file to simulate an error. I know that I could create a second instance of the open liberty container that loads the files necessary to make my application fail, but I want to avoid that kind of implementation. Do you have any suggestions?

Test containers has a module called Toxiproxy that should be able to help with this.
https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/toxiproxy/
You can add it as a proxy between your services and use it to simulate network issues like latency or timeouts between your services.

Thank you for your answer. Although I solved somehow my problem, I will check it.

It sounds like you want to deliberately force your code to emit a runtime exception, but you have no way of letting it know its in a test mode so whatever you do has to also be safe for use in a production environment. (I'm assuming when you said you cannot change configuration files you also meant things like environment variables?)
I am not aware of any special tools in OpenLiberty to force runtime exceptions, and if they were you'd need configuration to use them. One possibility would be to attach a debugger to your open liberty in your container. Then inside eclipse or your IDE of choice manually set the value of client to null to force an NPE.
If you need to be able to do this repeatedly as part of automated testing, I can't think of anything better than creating a second instance of the open liberty container.

Thank you very much for your answer. I managed to solve this by separating my success (200) tests from my failure (500) tests and pass system variable (per test class) that interferes with my Open Liberty container making my application to return an exception. For the 200 tests, I pass the legit system variable, for the 500 I pass something invalid.
